# How to load external js library in Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, aws-sdk, hmac, jsr223

I have the following code in a jsr223 sampler:

```
var key = "key";
var dateStamp = "20160329T134359Z";
var regionName = "us-east-1";
var serviceName = "execute-api";

   var kDate= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, dateStamp, "AWS4" + key, { asBytes: true})
   var kRegion= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, regionName, kDate, { asBytes: true });
   var kService=Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, serviceName, kRegion, { asBytes: true });
   var kSigning= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, "aws4_request", kService, { asBytes: true });
   vars.put("AWSKey", kSigning);
```

Now when I run it i get this error:
Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Crypto" is not defined. (#6) in  at line number 6

Obviously I dont have the crypto libs. However I am at loss on how to load them. I downloaded all the relavant js and put them in the /lib folder and still nothing.
I downloaded this file: https://github.com/Boussetta/CryptoJS-v3.1.2
Which handles the functions in the code above but for the life of me I have not idea how to import it.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go for JavaScript - there are 2 options:

1. Use Rhino `load()` method like:

   `load("crypto.js")`
2. Use [HmacUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) from JavaScript

   ```
   var rawhmac = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils.hmacSha1(key,data)
   var encoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(rawhmac)
   ```

However I would recommend going for option 3 - switch to "groovy" language instead of JavaScript, that way you will be able to:

- Re-use [Amazon authentication samples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AuthJavaSampleHMACSignature.html) in your test
- Get maximum performance and confidence as groovy scripts can be compiled while other languages are interpreted so groovy implementation will take less resources and will work faster. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more details.

Comment: thanks. i tried 1 and 2 and it did not work still. your sample url is broken, do you mind if you can resend? TIA