# How to import Cryptojs in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

In one of the http request we have to send encrypted value.

The encryption is done by the CryptoJs javascript libraries and Algorithm used is AES256.

I am new to Jmeter can anyone let me know how to import the CryptoJs libraries and how to use the function of same to encrypt and decrypt the same.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall answering something similar already, see [How to load external js library in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293800/how-to-load-external-js-library-in-jmeter)

Quoting myself:

> Use Rhino load() method like:
>
> ```
>    load("crypto.js")
> ```

Given the guy wasn't able to use the instruction here is a little bit extended version:

1. Download the required version of CryptoJS from the [releases page](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/releases) and unpack it somewhere
2. Using `load` method provide full path to `crypto-js.js` file like:

   ```
   /tmp/crypto-js-3.1.7/crypto-js.js
   ```
3. Access methods like

   - CryptoJS.SHA256(...)
   - CryptoJS.AES(...)
   - etc.

Demo:

[image: JSR223 JavaScript]

If the values are static and you don't have a lot of them a better idea could be storing them into a file and accessing via i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser.

Javascript is run through Rhino or Nashorn.

So your best option is to look at CryptoJS code and either:

- use it in a JSR223-Preprocessor using Javascript language
- Translate code to Groovy/Java using JSR223-Preprocessor + groovy

See:

- [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)